# What's special properties does the number 1372 have?

Tags: number-theory

I've just watched a Simpsons episode called "Burns Verkaufen der Kraftwerk" (S3E11). In that episode, when the German investors talk with Homer Simpson, they said they were from "The Land of Chocolate". Homer than imagines a land full of chocolate. In the beginning of the cut-away gag, there is a sign writing "Land of Chocolate Pop. 1372". Given the mathematical background of the Simpsons writers, I know that this 1372 is chosen because of some mathematical properties. Can anybody tell me what's special with the number 1372? Thanks.

Comment: 1372 is the smallest number that can not be written as the sum of 3 volumes of rectangular boxes with integer dimensions less than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For special properties of integers between $1$ and $9999$, take a look here:

[What's Special About This Number?](https://erich-friedman.github.io/numbers.html)

As regards 1372, it says that 1372 is the smallest number (greater than 2) that can not be written as the sum of 3 volumes of rectangular boxes with integer dimensions less than $10$.

An interesting property since the maximum volume of such 3 boxes is $3\cdot 9^3=2187$.

Comment: 1372  is the smallest number that can not be written as the sum of 3 volumes of rectangular boxes with integer dimensions less than 10. Obviously this can't be a coincidence what they used this number!

Answer (score 0):

After bit of digging, it's the number associated with a particular chocolate flavouring C1372., (https://www.spectrumchemical.com/OA_HTML/chemical-products_Chocolate-Natural-and-Artificial-Flavor-Concentrate_C1372.jsp), though who know which was named after the other!